# Installing ATLAS on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, atlas

I'm trying to install ATLAS on OSX but can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Here's the ATLAS install page:
http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/node6.html

Here is what I type into Terminal:

```
../configure -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=2400 --prefix= /Users/robertgrzesik/atlaslib --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/Users/robertgrzesik/Downloads/lapack-3.5.0.tgz
```

But it throws this error:

```
    gcc -I/Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall/..//CONFIG/include  -g -w -c /Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall/..//CONFIG/src/atlconf_misc.c
gcc -I/Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall/..//CONFIG/include  -g -w -o xconfig /Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall/..//CONFIG/src/config.c atlconf_misc.o 
./xconfig -d s /Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall/../ -d b /Users/robertgrzesik/ATLAS/osxinstall  -b 64 -D c -DPentiumCPS=2400 /Users/robertgrzesik/atlaslib -Si lapackref 1

ERROR around arg 12 (/Users/robertgrzesik/atlaslib).
USAGE: ./xconfig [flags] where flags are:
   -v <verb> : verbosity level
   -O <enum OSTYPE #>  : set OS type
   -s <enum ASMDIA #>  : set assembly dialect
   -A <enum MACHTYPE #> : set machine/architecture
   -V #    # = ((1<<vecISA1) | (1<<vecISA2) | ... | (1<<vecISAN))
   -b <32/64> : set pointer bitwidth
   -o <outfile>
   -C [xc,ic,if,sk,dk,sm,dm,al,ac] <compiler>
   -F [xc,ic,if,sk,dk,sm,dm,al,ac,gc] '<comp flags>'
   -Fa [xc,ic,if,sk,dk,sm,dm,al,ac,gc] '<comp flags to append>'
        al: append flags to all compilers
        ac: append flags to all C compilers
        gc: append flags to gcc compiler used in user-contributed index files.
        acg: append to all C compilers & the index gcc
        alg: append to all compilers & the index gcc
   -T <targ> : ssh target for cross-compilation (probably broken)
   -D [c,f] -D<mac>=<rep> : cpp #define to add to [CDEFS,F2CDEFS]
      eg. -D c -DL2SIZE=8388604 -D f -DADD__ -D f -DStringSunStyle
   -d [s,b]  : set source/build directory
   -f <#> : size (in KB) to flush before timing
   -t <#> : set # of threads (-1: autodect; 0: no threading)
   -m <mhz> : set clock rate
   -S[i/s] <handle> <val>  : special int/string arg
      -Si bozol1 <0/1> : supress/enable bozo L1 defaults
      -Si archdef <1/0> : enable/supress arch default use
      -Si ieee <1/0> : dis/allow optimizations that break IEEE FP standard
          (eg., NEON, 3DNow!)
      -Si latune <1/0> : do/don't tune F77 LAPACK routines
      -Si nof77 <0/1> : Have/don't have fortran compiler
      -Si nocygwin <0/1> : Do/don't depend on GPL cygwin library
                           (Windows compiler/cygwin install only)
   -tl <#> <list> : set # of threads, use list of affinity IDs
      -Si omp <0/1> : don'tuse/use OpenMP for threading
      -Si antthr <0/1/2> : nobuild/build/use Antoine's code for threading
      -Si lapackref <0/1>: Netlib lapack is not/is unpacked
                           to $BLDdir/src/lapack/ref
      -Ss kern <path/to/comp> : use comp for all kernel compilers
      -Ss ADdir <path/to/archdefs> : Get archdefs frm custom path
      -Ss pmake <parallel make invocation (eg '$(MAKE) -j 4')>
      -Ss f77lib <path to f77 lib needed by C compiler>
      -Ss flapack <path to netlib lapack>: used to build full lapack lib
      -Ss [s,d]maflags 'flags'
NOTE: enum #s can be found by : make xprint_enums ; ./xprint_enums
xconfig exited with 12
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out! So stupid, I put an extra space after "--prefix=". Haha